# How to tell Rails explicitly to reload a file on each request while in dev mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file in `app/models/tag.rb` which adds a method to a class in a gem:

```
class ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag

  def to_param
    name
  end

end
```

This is in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
```

Problem is that, even in development mode, Rails only loads this file when the server starts. How can I tell Rails to load this file on every request, at least in development mode?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if this doesn't work (perhaps you've tried it already).

There's a ruby method `load`.  Call it every time your app runs.  You can do that by adding it to your application_controller.rb file.

```
before_filter :reload_my_gem

def reload_my_gem
  load "[path_to_file]"
end
```

(I don't know how your app and gem run; it may be that `before_filter` does not make the call at the right time for your needs.)